# How to reference using endnotes, with endnotes grouped by chapter at the end of the book

Tags: bibliographies, cross-referencing, footnotes, endnotes

I'm trying to reference using footnotes, and to have these footnotes displayed as endnotes at the end of my book. Importantly, I want these endnotes to be grouped by chapter.

Here's an example of what I have in mind:

> **Chapter 1**
>
> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.<sup>1</sup>
> Nullam gravida nulla turpis, sit amet aliquet tellus malesuada
> eget.<sup>2</sup> Curabitur eu egestas urna, quis tempus massa. Nulla
> tristique pulvinar mauris malesuada pulvinar. Curabitur sed justo eget
> turpis euismod condimentum sit amet eu est.
>
> **Chapter 2**
>
> Integer vel sem lobortis, gravida leo sed, bibendum neque.<sup>1</sup>
> Morbi consequat eu mi eget sagittis. Pellentesque commodo mauris vel
> metus rhoncus malesuada. Etiam cursus dolor magna, sed posuere libero
> mattis vel.<sup>2</sup> Sed eu egestas velit. Nulla et porttitor
> mauris, a ultricies risus.<sup>3</sup>
>
> **Notes**
>
> *Chapter 1*
>
> <sup>1</sup> Carnap, Rudolf. The Logical Syntax of Language. London:
> Kegan Paul, 1937, p. 17.
>  <sup>2</sup> Ebbinghaus, H.-D., T. Flum,
> and W. Thomas. Mathematical Logic. Undergraduate Texts in Mathematics.
> Edited by J. H. Ewing, F. W. Gehring and P. R. Halmos. 2 ed. New York:
> Springer, 1994, pp. 18-40.
>
> *Chapter 2*
>
> <sup>1</sup> Dedekind, Richard. Essays on the Theory of Numbers.
> Chicago: The Open Court Publishing Company, 1901, p. 72. 
> <sup>2</sup> Lewis, David. "A Subjectivist's Guide to Objective
> Chance." Chap. 13 In Studies in Inductive Logic and Probability,
> edited by R. C. Jeffrey, 263-94. Berkeley: University of California
> Press, 1980, p. 165.
>  <sup>3</sup> Lakatos, Imre. "Proofs and
> Refutations (I)." The British Journal for the Philosophy of Science
> 13, no. 54 (1963), p. 21.
>
> **Bibliography**
>
> Carnap, Rudolf. The Logical Syntax of Language. London: Kegan Paul,
> 1937.
>  Dedekind, Richard. Essays on the Theory of Numbers. Chicago: The Open Court Publishing Company, 1901.
>  Ebbinghaus, H.-D., T.
> Flum, and W. Thomas. Mathematical Logic. Undergraduate Texts in
> Mathematics. Edited by J. H. Ewing, F. W. Gehring and P. R. Halmos. 2
> ed. New York: Springer, 1994.
>  Lakatos, Imre. "Proofs and
> Refutations (I)." The British Journal for the Philosophy of Science
> 13, no. 54 (1963): 7-25.
>  Lewis, David. "A Subjectivist's Guide to
> Objective Chance." Chap. 13 In Studies in Inductive Logic and
> Probability, edited by R. C. Jeffrey, 263-94. Berkeley: University of
> California Press, 1980.

As you can see, I then want to have one bibliography listing all references together at the end. (Don't worry about the specific format of the references, what matters to me is just how to achieve these endnotes grouped by chapter.)

I'd appreciate any suggestions for implementing these ideas! :)

Comment: The `memoir` class (a superset of `book`, report`, ...) provides what you are after. See section 12.6 ENDNOTES in the manual (`> texdoc memoir`).